# list(dictionary.values()) vs. dictionary.values()

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to return the list of values of a given a dictionary `dict`. How is `list(dict.values())` different than `dict.values()`.

Why is `dict.values` not iterable?

Comment: Where - and what reason or contraints were given for that explanation?

Comment: because dict.values() will not return a list?

Comment: `dict.values()` doesn't return a list, so if you must return a list, then it is better to use `list(dict.values())` because it actually does what you need it to do. Often, you don't really need a list, though, and you can use `dict.values()` just fine. Not always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is that in Python3 values() returns a *view*. It means that:

- it is not a list
- its content tracks the changes of the dictionary, while `list` will create a list and will not track the changes.

```
>>> d = { "one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3} 
>>> l = list(d.values()) 
>>> v = d.values() 
>>> d["one"] = 5 
>>> l 
[1, 2, 3] 
>>> v
dict_values([5, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to return the list of values of a given a dictionary dic

```
>>> d = {1:2,3:4}
>>> d.values()
dict_values([2, 4])
>>> list(d.values())
[2, 4]
```

As you see, `dict.values()` will not return a `list` object.

Comment: But it returns something that's equivalent to a list object for most intents and purposes… It really depends on your use case whether you *really* need an actual `list`…

Comment: @deceze I just followed the lines of the OP, in which s/he states a need to a `list`

Answer (score 0):

When ever we use `return list(dict.values())` the list of values is returned of type `<class 'list'>` but when we use `return dict.values()` we get values of `<class 'dict_values'>`.

```
>>> a = {1:3,2:6}
>>> list(dict.values()) 
>>> [3, 6]

>>> dict.values()
>>> dict_values([3, 6])
```

NB :  we can use something like `ls = list(foo()). which would convert the returned`dict.values()` to a list.